# LP problem: Does ratio of capacity refer to volume? Weight?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, constraints

I have to set up an LP problem based on this situation below:

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

Let $x_{i,j}$ denote amount of loot i in hold j

for i = 1,2,3 corresponding to materials, gold and spice

for j = 1,2,3 corresponding to forward, center and aft

We want to maximise profit

$$z=16\sum_j x_{1,j} + 36\sum_j x_{2,j} + 3\sum_j x_{3,j}$$

s.t.

Amount:

$$\sum_j x_{1,j} \le 60,000$$

$$\sum_j x_{2,j} \le 30,000$$

$$\sum_j x_{3,j} \le 15,000$$

Weight capacity:

$$\sum_i x_{i,1} \le 19,000$$

$$\sum_i x_{i,2} \le 30,000$$

$$\sum_i x_{i,3} \le 15,000$$

Volume capacity:

$$\sum_i c_i x_{i,1} \le 1,100$$

$$\sum_i c_i x_{i,2} \le 1,340$$

$$\sum_i c_i x_{i,3} \le 450$$

where $c_1 = 2, c_2 = 0.5, c_3 = 0.3$

Ratio for weight (wrong? use volume instead?):

$$\frac{\sum_i x_{i,1}}{\sum_i x_{i,2}} = 19/30$$

$$\frac{\sum_i x_{i,1}}{\sum_i x_{i,3}} = 19/15$$

$$\frac{\sum_i x_{i,2}}{\sum_i x_{i,3}} = 30/15$$

Ratio for volume (wrong? use weight instead?):

$$\frac{\sum_i c_i x_{i,1}}{\sum_i c_i x_{i,2}} = 1,100/1,340$$

$$\frac{\sum_i c_i x_{i,1}}{\sum_i c_i x_{i,3}} = 1,100/450$$

$$\frac{\sum_i c_i x_{i,2}}{\sum_i c_i x_{i,3}} = 1,340/450$$

Nonnegative:

$x_{i,j} \ge 0$

---

Are those right? To what do capacity ratios refers? Weight? Volume? It can't be both so which is it?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: Looks good as far as I can see.  I have no idea what the sentence "to maintain seaworthiness of the ship, the ratio of the contents..." is intended to mean.  Your interpretation as relating to ratios of weight and weight capacity seems reasonable, and these equality constraints can indeed be converted to linear equality constraints for the LP.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! ^-^ I mean why does ratio of capacity refer to weight and not volume? I guess it can't be both but why weight? Volume 'can indeed be converted to linear equality constraints for the LP' right?

Comment: The description of the problem gives me no clue if they mean ratios with respect to weight, or with respect to volume.  For general numbers, it is impossible for them to mean "both," since $$\frac{\mbox{loot $i$ weight}}{\mbox{loot $j$ weight}} = \frac{\mbox{(loot $i$ volume)}/c_i}{\mbox{(loot $j$ volume)}/c_j} $$  So fixing a weight ratio also fixes the volume ratio.

Comment: @Michael I thought so. Post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just posting what I wrote in comments above:

This work looks good as far as I can see.  From the problem description, it is not clear if the ratio constraint is with respect to weight or volume. It is reasonable to assume it is for weight.

For general numbers, it cannot be both weight *and* volume, since: 
$$ \frac{\mbox{loot $i$ weight}}{\mbox{loot $j$ weight}} = \left(\frac{\mbox{loot $i$ volume}}{\mbox{loot $j$ volume}}\right)\left(\frac{c_j}{c_i}\right)$$
and so, once the weight ratio is fixed for a particular pair, the volume ratio is also fixed.

Also, the weight ratio constraints indeed can be written as linear equality constraints, so it is valid for an LP.

Comment: But it's also reasonable to assume for volume?

Comment: I don't think it really matters.  The point is that you know how to write a linear program, not that you know about ship requirements.